# OBJECT INSTANTIATION in case of derived class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
    }
}


public class Derived : Base
{
    public new void SomeOtherMethod1()
    {
    }
}

**Base b = new Derived();

Derived d = new Derived();

Derived d=new Base();**
```

I am not able to understand object instantiation these three line above?I have a bit of confusion regarding the concepts of how objects are instantiated in case of Derived class.Can anybody help me about these concepts?

Confused Left portion and right portion of Equal sign ?

Comment: Well the first two are valid, the last isn't. You can use an instance of a derived class as if it were an instance of a base class. Could you be more precise about what you don't understand? (I strongly suspect that reading a good book will do more good than answers here for a conceptual issue like this, mind you.)

Comment: Look on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: And I imagine you're trying to override `SomeOtherMethod1` instead of just hiding parent implementation using `new`. If I'm correct, use `override SomeOtherMethod1` instead of `new SomeOtherMethod1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
public new void SomeOtherMethod1()
```

...with:

```
public override void SomeOtherMethod1()
```

That's if you want actual polymorphism (changing the implementation of the base member).

### About the other lines

This is known as *upcast*. Since `Derived` is of type `Base` because it inherits `Base`, a more concrete instance can be *upcasted* to a less concrete reference:

```
Base b = new Derived()
```

The other line is a *downcast*. For the same reason as the *upcast*, you can *downcast* an instance and store it in a more concrete typed reference, if the more concrete derives the less concrete.

The problem is that in your case, `Base` will never be of type `Derived`, because `Base` does not inherit `Derived`. But you can do the next *downcast*:

```
Base base = new Derived(); // This is an upcast again
Derived derived = (Derived)base; // Using an explicit downcast to Derived!
```